# Cannot edit drawable after mutate() and getConstantState().newDrawable() does not provide independent drawable

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, drawable

I want to create a signal light of three lights which are made from the same resource and tinted in its individual color (red, yellow, green) and being controlled by java code. However, it looks like I cannot mutate and create independent instances of the source drawable.

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/light1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/light2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/light3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Attempt:

```
        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(light1res);
        Drawable dw = ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, android.R.drawable.presence_invisible);
        dw.mutate();
        dw.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        iv1.setImageDrawable(dw);
```

Result: None of the three `imageView` get tinted. If I remove `dw.mutate()`, then all three imageViews get tinted though. If I replace dw.mutate() by `dw=dw.getConstantState().newDrawable()` then all imageViews get tinted either. If I do `dw.mutate().getConstantState().newDrawable()` the result is the same as with .mutate() (no effect on drawable editings) so nothing is being tinted. If i do `dw.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate()` then all ImageViews get the same changes so it's like not doing mutating at all. I can do all this and similar things at any line and the results remain the same.

It does not matter wether I use the function setColorFilter(...) or DrawableCompat.tint(...) after wrapping, the resulting behaviour is exactly the same as described above.

So it looks to me like after doing mutate(), changes on the drawable do not have any effects and .getConstantState().newDrawable() provides a drawable which still shares its states with the original.

Obtaining the drawable by iv1.getDrawable() makes no difference either.

Any ideas what's going on and how I could solve this particular, strange issue?

I'm using build tools 25.0.3 (compile sdk version api 25 Android 7.1.1) and testing on Android 5 and Android 7 phones (same results).

I know that many devs have issues with drawable states and tinting but apparently all could be solved by mutating and using the codes I mentioned here, so please consider this before you think this is a duplicated question.

Comment: I also invalidated the ImageViews with no success.

Comment: Can anyone test my code and confirm the issue?